# Трехмерные крестики-нолики

Tags: c++builder, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте! Не могли бы помочь вот в каком вопросе. Такая проблема: задали курсовую работу по программировании, игру "трехмерные крестики-нолики". Конечно, супер-пупер не собираюсь делать, но надо нарисовать три плоскости и сделать расстановку шариков, вот в этом вся проблема. Не могли бы объяснить (алгоритм решения) как это сделать? Нужно сделать в объектном.

Comment: Скажите, может быть, кто-нибудь знает где можно скачать хорошие готовые алгоритмы для игры крестики нолики 3*3*3 для C/C++ или кто-нибудь делал такой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.



Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как сделать? Нужно определиться с тем через что будете отрисовывать изображение. Вариантов множество: начиная от GDI, кончая DX и OpenGL. Но в любом случае придется изучать какую-то из этих технологий. Далее. Чтобы что-то вывести, нужно это самое что-то иметь. Если использовать DX и OGL, то нужно скомпоновать сцену, состоящую из примитивов (эти самые плоскости, шарики и освещение, без которого ничего не будет видно). Если же просто выводить пиксели на экран, то придется уже самому делать обработку своего 3-хмерного пространства и высчитывать куда какая точка сцены попадает и какого цвета будет конечный пиксель. Это уже немного сложнее. [Вот](http://tpdn.ru/library/articles/51/8555/), например, что для этого нужно и как это сделать.

По библиотеке GLUT пример могу предложить [такой](http://compgraphics.info/OpenGL/template_glut.php). Если уделите ему пять минут, то, думаю, дальше уже необходимую информацию сможете сами найти.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересные 2 статьи, давно такие искал!

Comment: Скажите, может быть, кто-нибудь знает где можно скачать хорошие готовые алгоритмы для игры крестики нолики 3*3*3 для C/C++ или кто-нибудь делал такой.
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @IvAn, вам уже дан один ответ. Исходники в гугле есть.